# Can I close an image in Gimp and have the entire program close?

Tags: gimp

I'm using GIMP 2.6.12.

When I'm done editing an image and want to close Gimp, I have to do the process twice.

The first closure will close the open image file. After that, GIMP remains open but in a state of "not open any file". Then I must press the "close" or use the pull down menu to completely exit from GIMP.

Is this normal or can I change this?

Comment: You might just want Ctrl+Q to quit immediately even if some file is opened

Comment: Multi-window mode is cool, but it's a real pain in the *ss to close all of them at the end. My solution: Alt-F2 -> "pkill gimp" Bonus: no confirmation asked :)

Comment: I think kill should be used when there is no other way.

Comment: kill just sends a SIGTERM signal by default. It asks the process to terminate. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal. From [the GIMP documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-file-close.html):

> 2.14. Close
>
> The Close command closes the active image. If the image is not in the
>   main window, then the window is closed also. **If the image is in the
>   main window, the image is closed but the window remains, empty.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: It used to be closing the toolbar would close everything, but now the toolbar just disappears.

Answer (score 10):

The behavior you want is now available in Gimp 2.8 by using single-window mode.

From the menu: *Windows > Single-window mode*

Comment: I do not wish to use single-window mode, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's abnormal, but it is indeed how the GIMP functions. It's not like the same window remains open, BTW, more like it opens a new empty window. In a way it's the equally absurd reverse from Windows, where clicking the Start button was needed to close it; here clicking the close gadget opens a window.

The developers consider this bug a feature, so it's unlikely to ever get fixed.

                                                                                                                                                                                                    Mysha

Comment: Gimp developers consider plenty of bugs features. It's quite annoying how Gimp got less usable with each new version.